# Swap buttons to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have something like this

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("options")[0]
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("line-type")) {
      // Remove active class from previous element
      document
        .querySelector(".line-type.is-active")
        .classList.remove("is-active");

      e.target.classList.add("is-active");
      currentLine = e.target.dataset.lineType;
      console.log("Current line: " + currentLine);
    }
  });
```

```css
.line-type { font-weight:bold }
.is-active { color:red }
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="lines" id="lines">
    <div class="line-type water-pipe is-active" data-line-type="water">
      Water pipe
    </div>
    <div class="line-type electricity-line" data-line-type="electricity">
      Electricity line
    </div>
    <div class="line-type internet-line" data-line-type="internet">
      Internet line
    </div>
    <div class="water-pipe" id="test">
      RYSUJ TU
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="clear-water-pipe">Clear active line</button>
</div>
```

Now it changes my line color on click of the button but i would like to swap it totally to select, on select change i need to change colors and currentLine. Any tip how to do it? I never moved button into html select. Thanks

Comment: Please update the CSS I made. It does not show the issue. What do you mean by swapping to select? The button or the list?

Comment: I got this now as a buttons, but need to make it work as a <select> element withj options such as Water Pipe Electricity Line Internet Line and then get it's data attribute, but when im trying to do it with addEventListener(change) it doesn't work so I need a bit help

Comment: Can you post your select/ change version instead of the button version so we have some idea?

Comment: I don't have select version yet because it's not working and i have trully no idea how to change it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-60753858-fabric-js-1720-6ke80 - here are buttons, need to change it to <select>

Comment: So post what you have. Because now we have some vague description like `need to make it work as a <select> element with options such as Water Pipe Electricity Line Internet Line and then get its data attribute`

Comment: I posted a codesandbox in earlier comment, had to edit, sorry about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210144/discussion-between-kacper-sitarz-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Your sandbox also does not work. Anyway, I see what you are trying Next time please post the code here instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start

```js
const linesData = {
  water: {
    linePoints: [],
    lineLines: [],
    color: "blue"
  },
  electricity: {
    linePoints: [],
    lineLines: [],
    color: "yellow"
  },
  internet: {
    linePoints: [],
    lineLines: [],
    color: "gray"
  }
};

let currentType;
let sel = document.createElement("select");
sel.id = "lineType"
sel.appendChild(new Option("Please select", ""));
sel.addEventListener("change", function() {
  currentType = this.value ? linesData[this.value] : {}
  console.log(this.value, currentType)
})
Object.keys(linesData).forEach(key => {
  const title = key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1) +" line";
  sel.appendChild(new Option(title, key));
});
document.getElementById("app").appendChild(sel)
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="350"></canvas>
</div>
```